# angular 2.0 mandatory refresh like $apply

Tags: javascript, angular

I am create an app to drag a component(angular2 component, same below) from a list and drop it into another component. In this process I used interactjs to drag and drop component. But when I drop it into another component, It only load the static html in the component template which dragged.

For example I have this component to be added into another

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component{
    selector:"sample"
}

@View{
    template:`<p>static content</p><p>{{contentToBind}}</p>`
}

class Sample{
    contentToBind:string= "I am the binding content."
}
```

when it added, it should looks like below

```
static content
I am the binding content.
```

But actually it just display static content like

```
static content
```

**You can check this example in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e9cdZVV1fkVCpe0DgDWE?p=preview).**

**And** then I bind a click HostListener to this Sample component, when I click the component has been already added into another component, "I am binding content" will appear(other event triggered is same).
I think due to interact it has jumped out of angular2's lifecycle.

**Any similar method as $apply() in angularJs 1.x?**

Comment: Probably the problem is that your variable name doesn't match the one in the template.

Comment: @EricMartinez I have checked this. Unfortunately, not this point...

Comment: sorry, I have updated the variable in the question.

Comment: Ok, so the best option now would be to create a plnkr to reproduce the issue or a repo to clone it. Probably is a zone issue.

Comment: I will update with a plnkr later.

Comment: @EricMartinez I have added plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interact is not a part of angular 2, maybe your code in Interact is out of angular 2 scope as you said.

You can use NgZone in your Interactjs file in plunker, I edit your code and it's worked now. You should send your event inside of NgZone.

something like this.

```
myParent.ngZone.run(
    () => {
        console.log("onDrop...");
        ce.drop("Hello");
    }
);
```

See it on plunker
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w17gbHXE1quEh2KiA2bC?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. This solution solves the issue and works fine.